# Installing Drupal on shared hosting before name servers are directed to it

Tags: drupal

I'm planning doing the following. From going through the Drupal forums and Stack Overflow I don't think it will be a problem but I haven't found this exact question anywhere else and I want to be sure there aren't any other issues to worry about:

-Installing Drupal (7) on new shared hosting account before the name servers are directed to it. Their convention is http://username.hostingcompany.com

-Once I'm ready to go live, I direct the nameservers for username.com to point to the site.

It seems like I may have to rewrite the base URL during the installation and then take off the rewrite once the nameservers are set up? But I don't see any other issues beyond that. Am I right?

Thanks and I hope this helps someone else with the same question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this works fine.  Drupal installations are almost completely portable from one base URL to another.  The only thing you may have to adjust is the value of `RewriteBase` in .htaccess, if you have clean URLs enabled.  But with the better clean URL support in Drupal 7, you may not even have to do that any more - try it without changing .htaccess first.

A similar case is if you have development and production versions of your site (a good practice).  The two versions can be hosted on different domains at different base URLs, and the code and database are completely portable between the two, with only the adjustment in `RewriteBase` needed.  To accomodate that, what I do is to have two .htaccess files: an ordinary .htaccess with `RewriteBase` set for production, and an alternate, .htaccess.devhostname, identical except with `RewriteBase` set for development.  Then I configure my development server to read that file by preference, i.e.

```
AccessFileName .htaccess.devhostname .htaccess
```

With just that change, I can copy code and databases back and forth and Drupal works fine in both locations.